# Excel Print to PDF to Folder

Tags: excel, pdf, directory

Going a bit crazy on this one. Not sure why this code isn't working. My PDF file is saving but its saving to my Documents folder instead of the directed file. It needs to go into this file to save the documentation and I have another code to send an email and attach this file from this directory as well.

```
Sub PrintPOPDFtoFolder()

   ChDir "R:\Procurement\Purchase Orders" & "\" 'files directory
   fileSaveName = ActiveSheet.Range("Q7") 'Name the PDF file

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
       fileSaveName _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False


    MsgBox "File Saved " & " " & fileSaveName

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of relying on `ChDir`, use the full filepath in the `ExportAsFixedFormat` call:

```
fileSaveName = "R:\Procurement\Purchase Orders\" & ActiveSheet.Range("Q7").Value
```